# Linear gradient in Activity gauge, HighCharts

Tags: jquery, android-activity, highcharts, gradient, gauge

I am trying to put a linear gradient in the pane of the activity gauge but unfortunately, its not giving the desired results. I have been using High Chart linear gradient documentation but it doesn't work in this aspect. Can anyone advice me on how to change the pane color of the chart from solid to a gradient which changes with respect to percentage.

```
$(function () {

    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'solidgauge'
        },

        pane: {
            startAngle: -150,
            endAngle: 150
        },


        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            plotBands: [{ // mark the weekend
                color: {
                    linearGradient: [300, 300, 0, 0],
                    stops: [
                        [0, 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'],
                        [1, 'rgb(150, 200, 155)']
                    ]
                },
                from: 0,
                to: 100
            }],
            tickPositions: [],
        },

    pane: {
                startAngle: 270,
                endAngle: 540,
                background: [{ 
                    outerRadius: '0%',
                    innerRadius: '70%',
                    backgroundColor: {
                    linearGradient: [300, 100, 0, 0],
                    stops: [
                        [0, 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'],
                        [1, 'rgb(150, 200, 155)']
                    ]

                },
                    borderWidth: 0
                }]
            },


        plotOptions: {
            gauge: {
                dial: {
                    radius: '100%',
                    backgroundColor: 'silver',
                    borderColor: 'black',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    baseWidth: 10,
                    topWidth: 1,
                    baseLength: '90%', // of radius
                    rearLength: '50%'
                }
            }
        },


        series: [{
            data: [80]
        }]

    });
});
```

Here is a JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/3.1.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/gauge-activity/

Comment: I fixed your code block by selecting it and pressing Ctrl+K. (Clicking the `{}` button would have worked too.) This indents the whole block by four spaces, which is what indicates to Stack Overflow that it should be treated as code. You can read about SO's Markdown support [in the help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Good luck!

Comment: Are you sure you want to use linear gradient iwth a gauge series, not a angular gradient? For the second case, you have to do a workaround by creating many points with different colors - so they will imitate gradient. Read the answer from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40236267/gradient-effect-with-graddually-fill-in-highchart-gauge/40243065#40243065 and check the demo how to do it.

Comment: basically I want a gradient in the pane of the gage which changes color with respect to the quantity till which the pane goes.